# $gcd\left(2^{2^n}+1, 2^{2^m}+1\right)$

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, fermat-numbers

Given two Fermat's number $a=2^{2^n}+1$ and $b=2^{2^m}+1$ with $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}, ~n,m\ge0~\wedge~n\ne m$. Prove $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

Comment: Why in the world was this question closed??

Comment: A, I didn't see the duplicate.